# Python infinite recursion

Tags: python, decorator, infinite-recursion

I was just playing around with a python function that changes itself and couldn't avoid infinite recursion. At some point I made this:

```
def mitsos(a):
    global mitsos
    def takis(f):
            def w(*args, **kargs):
                    ret = f(*args, **kargs)
                    return ret + 1
            return w
    mitsos = takis(mitsos)
    return a
```

This unexpectedly worked. If i call mitsos(1) multiple times the result is always by 1 higher than the previous result. Why doesn't it fall in infinite recursion though?

Answer (score 3):

Your original function is not recursive at all, less infinitely recursive. Function `mitsos` creates another function `takis`. Then it calls that function. The function `takis` creates another function `w` and returns it. The new function becomes the value of `mitsos`, and the original `mitsos` returns. Period.

The redefined function is one step-recursive, and it redefines `mitsos` again. The new `mitsos` is two-step recursive, etc. But none of them is infinitely recursive.

Comment: Yes but in 'mitsos' at the line:

Comment: mitsos = takis(mitsos) takis calls f to make w which is basically mitsos and in there it should alter mitsos again

Comment: Yes, it alters it. But it does not call it.

Comment: I am still confused. mitsos makes takis and calls it. But it calls it with itself as argument which argument takis calls. The argument which is mitsos makes a takis and calls it. Shouldn't that run forever?

Comment: Note that after a new `w()` is created (which could have called `mitsos()` recursively), it is actually never called. It is assigned to `mitsos`, and the original `mitsos` returns.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's understood now